# How to check whether current component is checkout as well as the user details who checkout using tridion coreservices

Tags: tridion, tridion-2011, tridion-core-services

I want to write small function to check whether passed Item Object is checkout in Tridion or not if yes then it will return "true" and also I want to get the details of user who has checkout the Item, using Tridion 2011 core services.

I know we have `TryCheckout` as well as `Checkout` in our `CoreServiceClient` but it returns Identifiable Object only.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You need to look at the LockType on the item. Consider doing something like this

```
SessionAwareCoreService2010Client client = new SessionAwareCoreService2010Client();
ComponentData data = (ComponentData)client.Read("tcm:300-85609", new ReadOptions());
FullVersionInfo info = (FullVersionInfo)data.VersionInfo;
```

The full version info contains all the info you need (i.e. CheckOutUser and LockType). LockType is an Enumeration defined by Tridion.ContentManager.Data.ContentManagement.LockType, and includes the following set of flags:

- **None** - The item is not locked.
- **CheckedOut** - The item is checked-out. This can mean either a temporary (edit) lock, a permanent lock (explicit check-out performed by user) or a workflow lock.
- **Permanent** - The item is permanently checked-out, that is using an explicit check-out action.
- **NewItem** - The item is a new item, that is it has been created, but not checked-in for the first time yet.
- **InWorkflow** - The item is in a workflow.

Comment: @Chris...thanks which LockType and what it will return as I want both details checkout as well as User details

Answer (score 0):

Below is the sample code to get the details of ItemCheckedout with Users details in it.

```
public static Dictionary<bool,string> ItemCheckedOutDetails(string ItemUri, CoreServiceClient client, ReadOptions readOpt, ItemType itemType)
{
    Dictionary<bool, string> itemDetails = null;
    FullVersionInfo itemInfo = null;
    if (itemType == ItemType.Component)
    {
        // reading the component data
        var itemData = (ComponentData)client.Read(ItemUri, readOpt);
        itemInfo = (FullVersionInfo)itemData.VersionInfo;
    }
    else if (itemType == ItemType.Page)
    {
        // reading the page data
        var itemData = (PageData)client.Read(ItemUri, readOpt);
        itemInfo = (FullVersionInfo)itemData.VersionInfo;
    }
    else if (itemType == ItemType.StructureGroup)
    {
        // reading the structuregroup data
        var itemData = (StructureGroupData)client.Read(ItemUri, readOpt);
        itemInfo = (FullVersionInfo)itemData.VersionInfo;
    }
    else if (itemType == ItemType.Publication)
    {
        // reading the Publication data
        var itemData = (PublicationData)client.Read(ItemUri, readOpt);
        itemInfo = (FullVersionInfo)itemData.VersionInfo;
    }
    else if (itemType == ItemType.ComponentTemplate)
    {
        // reading the component template data
        var itemData = (ComponentTemplateData)client.Read(ItemUri, readOpt);
        itemInfo = (FullVersionInfo)itemData.VersionInfo;
    }
    else if (itemType == ItemType.PageTemplate)
    {
        // reading the Page template data
        var itemData = (PageTemplateData)client.Read(ItemUri, readOpt);
        itemInfo = (FullVersionInfo)itemData.VersionInfo;
    }
    else if (itemType == ItemType.MultimediaType)
    {
        // reading the Multimedia Type data
        var itemData = (MultimediaTypeData)client.Read(ItemUri, readOpt);
        itemInfo = (FullVersionInfo)itemData.VersionInfo;
    }

    if (itemInfo != null)
    {
        if (itemInfo.LockType.Value == LockType.CheckedOut)
        {
            itemDetails.Add(true, itemInfo.CheckOutUser.Title);
        }
    }
    return itemDetails;
}
```

Comment: The LockType values are actually bitwise values and can also have the flag `LockType.Permanent` set next to `LockType.Checkout`. The latter if-statement therefore should be:
`if ((itemInfo.LockType.Value & LockType.CheckedOut) == LockType.CheckedOut)
        {
            itemDetails.Add(true, itemInfo.CheckOutUser.Title);
        }`

Comment: LockType.CheckedOut seems to be superceded by LockType.Reserved. If an item is LockType.Reserved then the CheckOutUser is blank, even if the item is also set as LockType.CheckOut.

Comment: This means that the check, in Manoj's code, should be:  `if (((objVersion.LockType.Value & LockType.CheckedOut) == LockType.CheckedOut) && ((objVersion.LockType.Value & LockType.Reserved) == 0))`

Comment: As of .Net v4.0 we can use the `HasFlag` method call for bitwise enums with the 'Flags' attribute: `if (info.LockType.Value.HasFlag(LockType.CheckedOut)){...}`